# Batch file written in notedpad with '>' shows '1>' in dos windows.

Tags: windows, batch-file, msdeploy

I am trying to log an output from MSDeploy command line script to a log file.

```
:: SYNC FILES--
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2\msdeploy.exe" -Verb:sync ^
-Source:AppHostConfig=Website1,ComputerName=Server1 ^
-Dest:AppHostConfig=Website1,ComputerName=Server2 ^
-Skip:SkipAction='Update',objectName=filePath,absolutePath=.*web.config$ ^
-Skip:SkipAction='Update',ObjectName=contentPath,absolutePath=c:\\inetpub\\apppools ^
-Skip:objectName=Binding ^
-EnableRule=DoNotDeleteRule > msdeploy.log
TIMEOUT /T 100
```

"> msdeploy.log" shows up as "1> msdeploy.log" and becomes unable to log anything.

Any help will be appreciated ?

Comment: What do you mean with `unable to log anything`? Does msdeploy output to the console or nothing, does it start?

Comment: No it does not output anything on screen when i have > msdeploy.log in batch file. When I remove that "> msdeploy.log" it outputs on dos screen. I am using "> msdeploy.log" so i can log that in a file which can be reviewed later.

Comment: Then it logs into the file, but perhaps not in the directory you suppose.  You could test it with `... > C:\msdeploy.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The redirection with `>` is the short form of `1>`, to redirect stream1.

This is not your problem.

But it could be a directory problem, so the file is created but not in the expected one.

This happens when the working directory is not the same as the directory where the batch resides.